# Scala, Spring or Hadoop as an Api service?

Tags: java, hadoop

I am starting a new Java application - and the current code base I am taking over - appears to have been built with Jetty and its writing out HTML markup directly from the servlet itself.

```
package root.web;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    public class HTML { 
        public static String getHead(int pin,boolean due,
                String fname, String lname){
         String HEAD = "";
    HEAD += "<!DOCTYPE html>";
    HEAD += " <html>";

    HEAD += " <head>";
```

I am interested in re-building the application using Scala, Spring or Hadoop - very keen to discuss this with links, tutorials to help develop a quick and secure api. It will be primarily be a "login system" with the user filling in forms - and having the data from these forms stored in a MySQL table and displayed as charts/tables/lists.

So I am keen to build the frontend using reactjs - and to have the Java application provide an API service.

-- Login service essentially -- forgot password, session handling, account changes - so a CRUD of sorts

-- Then the user will fill in set of forms -- and so a GETDATA of results specific to the logged in user

please advise, code samples, tutorials, links. I predict it would be easier/quicker and more secure to start a fresh Scala, Spring or Hadoop project and use query builders - to secure the db -- if a mysql or mongodb should be used and if it makes much of a difference in this case, creating a JSON api service, CRUD application for a login handling?

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop is completely unsuitable for this task. It's a distributed storage / compute platform, similar to Google's MapReduce or Amazon's EMR -- it has nothing to do with web development, even for an API.

If you want to write a web application, you need a web application framework. Hadoop is not that.

Comment: What about Scala? I have used Spring MVC in the past - but often I see roles looking strongly for Scala and Hadoop (big data) positions. Hadoop is considered an open-source framework - but its not suited as a web application framework? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Hadoop

Comment: _I've never seen html markup being built like this -- is this a non-framework usage of connecting to the db?

Comment: please elaborate more -- why is Hadoop unsuitable - I hear its in depand ALL the time for big data applications -- what about Scala or Spring -- I hear more scala roles then spring roles etc.. -- please discuss

Comment: Of those three technologies, only Spring is a web application framework. Scala is a programming language, and Hadoop (as I said in my answer) is a storage/compute platform. They're separate technologies, not substitutes for one another.

Comment: I see - so Scala is like -- what coffeescript is for javascript? -- So really for this - still go with Spring? Or what other Java web application would you vouch for?

Comment: Scala is a separate programming language. It runs on the JVM, but is significantly different from Java. With regard to Spring, I've never used it, and I don't know what your requirements are, so I have no idea whether it'd be appropriate here.

Comment: its a user database system - login system -- when the user is logged in - they are requested to fill in some forms -- the system is also to show the results for these forms -- so its a user database system with put/get form data